# create a ping with true or false response in json

Tags: json, node-red

I am using node red "node-red-node-ping" to ping 192.168.0.71. The response looks like this

```
192.168.0.71 : msg : Object
object
payload: 0.376
topic: "192.168.0.71"
_msgid: "f766d646.764dc8"
```

if the ip address is not ping-able, payload is "false", and if found the payload returns trip time in ms. (0.376)

I need to use the function node (json) to change the trip time numeric response to "true" and keep the false response if the ip was not found

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: hint: any number other than 0 evaluates to true in Javascript

Comment: I am a copy/Paste code guy ;) I honestly don't understand the language. I have been all over google and can't figure this one out. Loving Node Red because i don't have to deal with the code for the most part

Comment: Then now's a good time to learn

Comment: not today when i am trying to get my project completed

Comment: If it's a school project even less reason for me to just hand you an answer

Comment: your not helpful with these responses. NO its not for school. it is a monitoring project for radio transmition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to branch based on whether the node is "pingable", which is what a `switch` node does. Add a rule to check if `msg.payload` > `0` (the number), and send the msg to port #1. Add another rule set to "otherwise" which sends the other "false" msgs to port #2. Then wire port #1 to a `change` node which sets `msg.payload` to the value "true".

Comment: only thing i would have said different was to wire port 2 which returns the false directly to my output node. In my case was a dashboard switch. Thank you for your response!

Comment: I think that was implied, since i only mentioned wiring the output of port #1 to the change node...